# How to make paste work like everywhere else in Vim

Tags: editor, vim

I've been using Vim for quite some time. There's one thing I'm still not used to and will never get used to... it copying/pasting *after* the cursor. It drives me nuts and I have to stop and think about that before copying or pasting anything.

For example if I have "hello worl" highlighted in "hello world" it'll copy "hello world" even tho the "d" is not highlighted. Same as pasting.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you, say, press `v` when `h` is highlighted, then move to `l` and press `y` it will yank exactly what you asked for — `hello worl`. Are you sure you don't advance cursor to `d`? And are you sure you use `y`? I suspect that you either do `Y` or you don't see the cursor as part of your highlight.

Comment: Check if the cursor is made invisible by something in your configuration.

Comment: Doesn't work like that for me in native vim or MacVim. It's been like that on multiple computers and OSs.

Comment: Cursor is a bit tricky part to compare with "everywhere else". Because in vim there's a character under cursor, whereas "everywhere else" has  cursor *between* characters…

Comment: @OscarGodson, what exactly is the sequence of characters? I've just tested it in `mvim`.

Comment: Exact steps: Type `Hello World`. Now, at the start, before H, press v. Press the right arrow 4 times. `Hell` will be highlighted. press y. Now, on a new line, press p. Youll notice `Hello` is pasted.

Comment: Also, after pasting, it says `Hello` but the cursor is at `Hell|o`

Comment: open mvim, `Ahello world<ESC>0v/ld<ENTER>yA<ENTER><ESC>p`

Comment: Cursor can not be at `Hell|o` — there's a character *under* cursor in `vim`.

Comment: So, if the character under cursor is `o`, then `o` is highlighted.

Comment: Yes, you're totally right. There's a character technically under the cursor, but my cursor is not a block. It's a bar. I was wondering if I can change the behavior of this. I know it's how Vim works out of the box. See this as to what my cursor looks like (which makes it hard to visualize while working): http://cl.ly/image/220L0q0A0V17

Comment: That's a problem with your colorscheme or your vimrc. Could you show both? Also, the cursor is supposed to blink. Vim doesn't do anything silly by himself. If it hides the cursor it is certainly because you tell it to do so.

Comment: Yes, must be a color scheme, but you said it works like this everywhere for you? Even in terminal?

Comment: So, yes, in terminal. If I have a string (1234) and I put the cursor at (123|4) and paste "F" it pastes between 3 and 4 making 123F4. In Vim, if I use native paste it acts this way too. If I use Vim paste it pastes _after_ the cursor, or, what visually looks like after the cursor. I can record a video of any/all of these things if you want.

Comment: You didn't say how you paste. In `vim`, if you put using `p`, it inserts after the character under cursor, if you use `P` — before. in case of `123|4` (`4` under cursor, it will produce `p`: `1234F` and `P`: `123F4`). So there's no need to change `vim` behaviour, you need to change yours (`p` vs `P`). But you still have cursor representation issue… Try different color schemes?

Comment: In normal mode, you put the cursor *on* `3` or *on* `4`. In insert mode, the cursor is between `3` and `4`. In normal mode, you either `p` after the cursor or `P` before the cursor. In insert mode, you are supposed to do `<C-r>"` to paste the content of the unnamed register. You should change how the cursor is displayed back to normal and use Vim properly. For reference, in GVim/MacVim, the cursor is a bar in insert mode and a block in normal mode while in CLI Vim it's always a block.

Comment: Awh, I see. Thats what I wanted. P not p. Perfect. How can I copy before too? Y doesn't do that. Thanks

Comment: `y` always includes the cursor.

Comment: @romainl, I don't think you can put from vim buffer in insert mode. You can paste from system clipboard, I believe, this is different.

Comment: `Y` is yanking a whole line, I think. and `y` always includes cursor as @romainl says.

Comment: Of course you can: `<C-r>"`, `<C-r>a`, `<C-r>0`, etc. and that's a register, not a buffer.